# Powershell Parameter Assignment fails

Tags: powershell, parameters

One of my Parameter assignments in the param section list below get the below listed error:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $compress = 'Optimal',
```

+     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $compress = 'Optimal',
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable
or a property.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide

I've also tried putting it in Double Quotes.  It makes no senses that you can't define a default value to a parameter.

---

Editing into the question from author's comment, here's the full parameter declaration:

```
param( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
[Alias("Z")] 
[String] 
$zipfile, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
[Alias("D")] 
[String] 
$filedir, 

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
$compress = 'Optimal', 

[Switch]$Append, 

[System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]$Compression = $compres 
)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that parameter definition. Can you show the entire `param()` definition? Or a [mcve]? What version of PowerShell?

Comment: Unless you are on a legacy OS/PowerShell version that does not have all the recent cmdlets. Why are you not just using Compress-Archive directly? It's why it exists. Something else in your code is causing this issue.

Comment: Here is the entire param section:                                                                                        param(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Alias("Z")] [String] $zipfile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [Alias("D")] [String] $filedir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $compress = 'Optimal',
    [Switch]$Append,
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]$Compression = $compres )

Comment: They have not upgraded PowerShell current Version is 4.0